# `kubectl` not found. If you need it, try: 'minikube kubectl -- get pods -A'

Tags: kubernetes, windows-10, kubectl, minikube

I installed `minikube` in `Windows 10` . I am able to start `minikube`

```
**C:\WINDOWS\system32>minikube start
* minikube v1.15.1 on Microsoft Windows 10 Pro 10.0.18363 Build 18363
* Using the hyperv driver based on existing profile
* Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
* Restarting existing hyperv VM for "minikube" ...
* Preparing Kubernetes v1.19.4 on Docker 19.03.13 ...
* Verifying Kubernetes components...
* Enabled addons: storage-provisioner, default-storageclass
* kubectl not found. If you need it, try: 'minikube kubectl -- get pods -A'
* Done! kubectl is now configured to use "minikube" cluster and "default" namespace by default**
```

But there is a warning in above output ( 2nd last line ) says
`kubectl not found. If you need it, try: 'minikube kubectl -- get pods -A'`

After that I executed this command too `minikube kubectl -- get pods -A`

Still getting below error while trying `kubectl`

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>kubectl
'kubectl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Minikube installs `kubectl` inside of itself.

So to use the `kubectl` which you installed via minikube, you have to prepend the command arguments with `minikube kubectl --`. For example:

```sh
# the same as `kubectl version --client`
minikube kubectl -- version --client
```

For convenience, you may want to add an alias in your shell configuration.

Source: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/kubectl/

Answer (score 4):

`kubectl` is wrapped around `minikube`.

Don't forget to add a `--` after `minikube kubectl`

```
minikube kubectl -- describe pod kube-scheduler-minikube --namespace kube-system
minikube kubectl -- get pods --namespace kube-system
```

Answer (score 2):

You have installed `minikube`, `kubectl` is not a part of minikube package.

It says when you do `minikube start` that `kubectl` is not present and if you need to you can use `minikube kubectl` instead.

This is also mentioned [here](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/)

```
If you already have kubectl installed, you can now use it to access your shiny new cluster
```

Answer (score 1):

It means that the kubectl might not be present on your machine or that it is not added to your PATH.

You can follow [these instructions](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#install-kubectl-on-windows) to install it either by downloading executable or by using `curl`:

```
curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.19.0/bin/windows/amd64/kubectl.exe
```

After that add the [binary to PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9546345/12237732).

You can run `kubectl version --client` to ensure correct version is downloaded.

Comment: It is installed inside of `minikube` and can be accessed via `minikube kubectl --` e.g. `minikube kubectl -- version --client`

Answer (score 1):

you can create a symbolic link to minikube’s binary named ‘kubectl’.

```
ln -s $(which minikube) /usr/local/bin/kubectl
```

REF: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/kubectl/

Answer (score 0):

Use doskey.exe to create an alias for kubectl.

Example:

```
doskey kubectl="%PROGRAMFILES%\Kubernetes\Minikube\minikube.exe" kubectl -- $*
```

You might need to update the path if you've installed minikube somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Use this command:

```
alias kubectl="minikube kubectl --"
```